# Implicit conversion from data type varbinary to date SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, insert

I have a procedure which takes a `date` value as parameter and then inserts the date value in a table:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.procInsert
    @employed_on    DATE
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.TBL(EMPLOYED_ON)
    VALUES(@employed_on)
END
```

however i am getting this error:

> Implicit conversion from data type varbinary to date is not allowed.
>   Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

I tried to use `convert` but its not working.

UPDATE
i found my mistake. i swapped the variables for insert.

Comment: Check input format of date. It might differ from sql server settings. See my answer.

Comment: I don't see any attempt to convert from varbinary to date. How are you calling the stored procedure?

Comment: i get the error message while creating the procedure!

Comment: @Tarounen please close question.

Comment: actually i think i cant close it. not enough reputation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found my mistake. i swapped the variables for insert.